# Splashscreen theme displayed on every preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen

I create a SplashScreen, using my own theme...

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_test</item>
</style>
```

...applyed as main theme of app while app loading...

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher"
```

...and then changed to AppTheme in onCreate of started Activity:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

All works, but i have funny problem. All previews of the screen using Launcher theme, and now it seems like:

[image]

I just can't work this way. =)

How can i avoid this "problem"?

Comment: set some other background to the parent layout

Answer (score -1):

In you `@drawable/splash_test` you can set nullable drawable or just different color for `tools` namespace.

For example, when you have this type splash screen (just color + icon):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/color_background" />

    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="150dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

You can set new `drawable` in `tools` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      <--- ADDED THERE #1
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/color_background"
        tools:drawable="@color/color_for_preview" />     <--- ADDED THERE #2

    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="150dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:drawable="@color/color_for_preview" />     <--- ADDED THERE #3

</layer-list>
```

So for `tools` like Android Studio Preview, there will `color_for_preview` color.